# How to get the first 3 parts of an ip adress in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get first 3 parts of the ip address  in php.

For example let us consider the ip address as

```
"1.2.3.4";
```

then I would like to get

```
"1.2.3";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this to get the first 3 parts:

```
$nums = explode(".", "1.2.3.4") ;

echo $nums[0]. "." .$nums[1]. "." .$nums[2] ;
```

Or you can also do it in this way:

```
$ip = "1.2.3.4";
$dotPosition = strrpos($ip, '.'); //getting position of the last dot
echo substr($ip, 0, $dotPosition); //getting the characters until that position.
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ip = "1.2.3.4";

echo substr($ip, 0, strrpos($ip, '.'));
```

Outputs

> 1.2.3

This uses [`strrpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the last occurrence of the `.` character.

Answer (score 3):

```
$nums = explode(".", "1.2.3.4") ;
echo "{$nums[0]}.{$nums[1]}.{$nums[2]}" ; //echoes 1.2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ip = "1.2.3.4";

$nums = explode(".",$ip) ;

echo $nums[0].".".$nums[1].".".$nums[2] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function:

```
function GetFirstThree($ip) {
    if(strlen($ip) <= 10) {
        $pos = strpos($ip, '.', strlen($ip)-3);
    } else {
        $pos = strpos($ip, '.', strlen($ip)-4);
    }
    $ip = substr($ip, 0, $pos);
    $ip = substr($ip, 0, strlen($ip));
    return $ip;
}

echo GetFirstThree("127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$ip = "1.2.3.4"
$firstThreeOctetOfIp = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $ip), 0, 3)); // "1.2.3"
```

1. `explode` the IP to get an array with 4 values
2. `array_slice` to get an array with required values
3. `implode` to get a string from the final array