# mysql wildcard IN database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an online game where i would like to ban repeat offenders from registering.

I made a simple ip-ban by storing ip addresses in table, and the code looks something like this:

```
    $ipadr = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $query="SELECT * FROM banned WHERE ip = '$ipadr'";

// if num results > 0, then the user is not allowed to register
```

However, some users keep changing their ip-address to come back.
So i would like to be able to add ip-ranges to the database
f.ex 187.15.200.*

Now how can i do something like this?

I imagine it could work with a query containing a reverse LIKE, but i don't know how to formulate it

```
example: SELECT * FROM banned WHERE '$ipadr' like ip%
```

Comment: You mean you don't know how to use LIKE?

Comment: So you want to prevent a registered user's neighbour from playing your game?

Comment: And don't forget IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

you need a php function like this to get the ip address first three elements of the ip address so you can then query off of them like so.

```
function GetFirstThree($ip) { // fnkr user wrote this function in another post just to give him credit
    if(strlen($ip) <= 10) {
        $pos = strpos($ip, '.', strlen($ip)-3);
    } else {
        $pos = strpos($ip, '.', strlen($ip)-4);
    }
    $ip = substr($ip, 0, $pos);
    $ip = substr($ip, 0, strlen($ip));
    return $ip;
}
```

look at the post i linked to see appropriate ways to get the first three elements of the ip address.. once you have it its just a simple `like` with wildcard in mysql.

execute your query with wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM banned WHERE '$ipadr' like '{$ip}%'
```

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938994/how-to-get-the-first-3-parts-of-an-ip-adress-in-php)